# SQL Data Modeler Automatically Creating Entity_ID

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using `Oracle SQL Data Modeler` to make a logical model. When the logical model is engineered to the relational model, it is automatically creating a new attribute `[ENTITY_NAME]_ID` in the relational model.

The entity already has a primary key that is guaranteed to be unique through domain administration. I've tried searching the Internet, messing around with primary keys, and more. This is a strong entity.

[Logical Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IGKn.png)

[Relational Model where Activity_ID has been automatically created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovuJd.png)

Comment: I just created an entity, PEOPLE, with attributes SSN, NAME, and DOB. SSN i marked as PRIMARY UID. I then engineered to relational design. SSN was made the PRIMARY KEY, and no PEOPLE_ID column was generated - so I can't reproduce your scenario based on the 2 screen shots

Comment: Could you embed the pics in the post itself, so we don't have to click out to see them? And you could add a screenshot of the entity properties, with the attributes page showing?

Comment: Or post to this our Oracle forums where you can post more details, and i can reply with pictures, etc.